KUBEFLOW notebook - add custom configuration field
When creating a new notebook I added under Configurations options for nvidia runtime and access to Kubeflow pipelines. Those are both added with a checkbox to toggle on or off which all map to PodDefault components. This is what I have available at the moment:

Now I want to add the ability to create a k8s secret with a git access token when creating the notebook so that the users don't have to worry about k8s stuff.
I've seen some older versions of Kubeflow where it was possible to type yaml-like structure into the config but can't seem to figure it out with newer versions. The tokens are generated by users and as such can't be obtained from within the cluster.
Example workflow:

Select the create notebook button.
Scroll to configurations.
Add access token (copy-paste).
Backend creates a secret within the user's namespace containing the token.
Token is injected into the container as an ENV var to be used with git pull and such.

If there is a better way of doing what I ultimately need, I'm more than happy to do it!

sorry if I’m not on topic with your question, but I was wondering if I could take a look at your NVIDIA runtime PodDefault YAML file. I’m currently working on it myself and haven’t quite figured it out yet. Thank you

I use something called Kyverno to mutate pods based on them having a simple label "usenvidia" : true. then Kyverno will mutate the starting pod to insert runtime: nvidia into the pod before it starts.
